# How can I create typescript hydrate typings?

Tags: typescript, types

There's a very good chance this question is a duplicate, but however it may have been asked before, I'm not finding it.

I have two objects, a request and a report.  I've seen this referred to as object hydration.  This is an example of this input/output that I'm trying to get correct typings for.

```
const whatGoesIn = {
  name: true,
  age: true,
}

const whatComesOut = {
  name: "Seph",
  age: 29,
}

// I'm trying to make a function which takes a request of properties, and returns those properties filled
function report(request: typeof whatGoesIn): typeof whatComesOut {}
```

---

Here is what I've tried:

```
export type ReportRequest<OUTLINE> = {[key in keyof OUTLINE]?: true};

// Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof OUTLINE'
export type Reporter<OUTLINE, REQUEST = ReportRequest<OUTLINE>> = 
  (fillMe: REQUEST) => Pick<OUTLINE, keyof REQUEST>;

// Error: 'request' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
export type Reporter<OUTLINE> = 
  (request: ReportRequest<OUTLINE>) => Pick<OUTLINE, keyof request>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
export type Reporter<OUTLINE> = 
  (request: ReportRequest<OUTLINE>) => Pick<OUTLINE, keyof typeof request>;
```

In the first one where `REQUEST = ReportRequest<OUTLINE>`, REQUEST could be overwritten, so it wasn't inherent that it would have the same keys as OUTLINE.  In the latter attempt, I just needed to add typeof to make request a type instead of a value.